# iTunes CPU usage

Tags: macos, itunes, cpu-usage

iTunes on Mac OS X 10.5 is consistently using 10-11% of the cpu when playing one song. I understand that iTunes is a resource hog and my iTunes library is pretty big but could any other programs be acting on it, or are there any steps I can take to reduce the cpu usage?

Comment: are you using smart playlists?

Comment: I usually use party shuffle or shuffle through a smart playlist. Would that actively increase cpu usage?

Comment: Party shuffle?  What version are you using?

Comment: Also, what are your machine specs?

Comment: I'm using iTunes 8.2.1 on a late 2008 2.4ghz Macbook Pro with 2 gbs of ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes uses about 6% CPU on my 2.4 GHz Core 2 Duo to play a 238 kbs (VBR) MP3.  But, so does VLC playing the same song.  Playing the song from the command line with Sox takes about 3%. It seems reasonable to me, decoding compressed music is not free.

!0% could be about right on a slower processor.  My G4 is unavailable for comment right now.

Visualizer takes a lot of CPU.    Equalizer adds a percent or so, as well.

Comment: I see the same usage on my old macbook.